# If the value is NULL, return upper-level value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got this query:

```
SELECT
    `mp__reference`.`referenceid`
    , `mp__reference`.`description`
    , `mp__reference`.`starts`
    , `mp__reference`.`ends`
FROM
    `mp`.`mp__portal`
INNER JOIN `mp`.`mp__revision` ON (`mp__portal`.`revisionidfk` = `mp__revision`.`revisionid`) 
INNER JOIN `mp`.`mp__campaign` ON (`mp__revision`.`campaignidfk` = `mp__campaign`.`campaignid`)
INNER JOIN `mp`.`mp__helperusergroupcampaign` ON (`mp__helperusergroupcampaign`.`campaignidfk` = `mp__campaign`.`campaignid`)
INNER JOIN `mp`.`mp__usergroup` ON (`mp__helperusergroupcampaign`.`usergroupidfk` = `mp__usergroup`.`usergroupid`)
INNER JOIN `mp`.`mp__helperuserusergroup` ON (`mp__helperuserusergroup`.`usergroupidfk` = `mp__usergroup`.`usergroupid`)
INNER JOIN `mp`.`mp__user` ON (`mp__helperuserusergroup`.`useridfk` = `mp__user`.`userid`)
INNER JOIN `mp`.`mp__position` ON (`mp__position`.`portalidfk` = `mp__portal`.`portalid`)
INNER JOIN `mp`.`mp__group` ON (`mp__group`.`positionidfk` = `mp__position`.`positionid`)
INNER JOIN `mp`.`mp__reference` ON (`mp__reference`.`groupidfk` = `mp__group`.`groupid`)
WHERE userid = $_SESSION['userid']
AND MD5(groupid) = $_SESSION['groupid']
```

You can consider the entities: campaign <- revision <- position <- group <- reference as "daisychained" together from upper to lower level.

All of them contains the attribute "starts" and "ends".

I need to check if a lower level value is set. If not, it returns the next upper level value like this pseudocode:

```
if (reference.starts) then
  return reference.starts
else if (group.starts) then
  return group.starts
else if (position.starts) then
  return position.starts
etc... and the same thing for .ends
```

Yes, I could extract all of the values and then do a post-comparison - but I want to learn efficient SQL-querying.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
COALESCE (reference.starts, group.starts, position.starts, ...);
```

The first non `NULL` value will be returned.

Comment: YES, works flawlessly. I actually tried the command earlier; must have used it wrong, somehow.

Comment: No problem. Alternatively and in particular if you want to compare with other values than `null` - you might have a look at the `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ...` function (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html)